# Why is ASP.NET site not available to users on the LAN once I logout of the remote desktop

Tags: asp.net, iis, remote-desktop

I developed an ASP.NET website that is hosted on a client's machine and can only be accessed by their employees.  All works well provided that I am logged in to the system via a remote desktop connection; however, once I log out, their employees are no longer able to access the system.

The site generates the following error:

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This site does connect to the database, so all appears to work until an Interop.Excel call is made.

It has been a while since I set this site up but I vaguely remember having to set the security configurations before IIS enabled it to run as a service.  Is it possible that my login credentials are tied to the site being able to run Interop.Excel commands?  If so, how do I modify them so that anyone attempting to access the site from behind the firewall is able to do so?

Comment: "Cannot access the system" and "site generates an error" are different outcomes. Which is it? If the site is generating an error, it would help to see the code that is executing when the error is thrown.

Comment: They are able to access the site.  The error is generated once they press a button that creates a spread sheet.